# Can anyone explain decomposable and indecomposable groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

in my book,

Groups are decomposable if it is direct product of two proper-nontrivial groups.

Otherwise, they are indecomposable.

What I don't understand is that what is " product of two proper-nontrivial groups"?

$\mathbb{Z} _{21}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} _{3} \times \mathbb{Z} _{7}$

Is it indecomposable? $\mathbb{Z} _{3}$ and $\mathbb{Z} _{7}$ are cycles groups

Can anyone give me an example decomposable groups?

Comment: You have given an example of a decomposable group, according to your definition, by stating $\mathbb{Z}_{21}$ is isomorphic to the direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7$, as the isomorphism implies that two cyclic subgroups (of order 3 and 7, respectively) exist in $\mathbb{Z}_{21}$ with trivial (only the identity element) intersection.

Comment: Is Z21 decomposable? I don't still understand.

Comment: The definition you give for decomposable group is in terms of a direct product.  You need to know what a direct product of groups is, and what a "proper nontrivial subgroup" is.  Which of these are you unclear about?

Comment: proper nontrivial subgroup! what does that really mean in this context?

Comment: If you know what a subgroup $H$ of group $G$ means, "proper" subgroup means $H$ is not equal to $G$ and "nontrivial" means $H$ is more than just the identity subgroup, $\{e\}$, of $G$.

Comment: Oh, Maybe I just misunderstood a definition. So, G is decomposable if it is direct product of nontrival subgroups of G?

Comment: Yes.  Now that you know, you can probably see that the textbook was building up to this idea in stages.

Comment: Thank you, I just got a wrong idea. I did not realize that "proper nontrivial subgroups" are subgroups of G

Answer (score 5):

The word "decomposable" is used in connection with various algebraic objects: permutations, modules, and (as here) groups.  Often (but not always) the sense is consistent between settings, that an object can be expressed in a well-defined way in terms of two or more smaller objects.

For groups the definition is given that a group $G$ is *decomposable* iff it is the direct product of two proper, nontrivial subgroups, say $G = H_1 \times H_2$ where $H_1,H_2$ are subgroups of $G$, but neither is all of $G$ and neither is the trivial subgroup (consisting only of the identity element).

Now it happens that there is some redundancy in this definition, because if $H_1$ were the trivial subgroup, that would force $H_2$ to be all of $G$, and conversely.  So, as long as we are considering *internal* direct products for $G$, it would have been enough to require $H_1,H_2$ both nontrivial, or to require both to be proper subgroups.

This makes for a nice analogy with *composite* integers, which may be defined as nonzero numbers that can be expressed as the product of two "smaller" integers (or as the product of two nonunit integers).  Indeed in a finite group $G$ necessarily $|G|$ would be a composite number because $|G|=|H_1|\cdot |H_2|$.

One thing to keep your eye on is the requirements of a direct product, that $H_1 \cap H_2 = \{e\}$ is the trivial subgroup, and that every element of $G = H_1 H_2$ can be expressed as an element of $H_1$ times an element of $H_2$.

Finally a comment about the relationship between being *indecomposable* (not a decomposable group) and being a *simple* group.  A simple group has no nontrivial, proper normal subgroups (by definition).  But a decomposable group $G = H_1 \times H_2$ has at least two nontrivial, proper normal subgroups, namely $H_1$ and $H_2$.

Thus decomposable implies *not* simple, and taking the contrapositive, a simple group must be an indecomposable group.  However the converse is not true; some indecomposable groups are not simple.  For more discussion of this, see the older Question [Are finite indecomposable groups necessarily simple?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85573/are-finite-indecomposable-groups-necessarily-simple).

Comment: Just to be safe, does the definition of decomposable only allow two groups? That is, can I consider for example that $G=H_1 \times H_2 \times H_3$ falls into the definition?

Comment: @Hopmaths:  Since that "triple product" is a direct product of two groups, $H_1 \times H_2 \times H_3$ amounts to $(H_1 \times H_2) \times H_3$.  Check the definition in your textbook.