# characterizations of decomposable groups via normal complements and generalizations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, category-theory, direct-product

I'm trying to understand the relationship between internal and external aspects of products. Having read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85954/223002), I formulated the proposition below (with an added part) and attempted a proof.

**Proposition.** For a group $G$, TFAE.

1. $G$ is decomposable, i.e $G\cong K_1\times K_2$.
2. There exists $N,H\vartriangleleft G$ which are complements in the sense $N\cap H=\bf 0$ and $NH=G$.
3. There exist subgroups $K_1,K_2$ with $K_1\vee K_2=G$ such that "multiplication" $K_1\times K_2\to K_1\vee K_2=G$ given by $(a,b)\mapsto ab$ is  an injective group homomorphism (hence isomorphism by the universal property of the join of subobjects).

*Proof.* $[1\implies 2]$ Suppose $G= K_1\times K_2$ and let $j_1,j_2$ denote the unit injections of the factors to the product. If $\pi_1,\pi_2$ are the projections then $j_1=\ker \pi_2,j_2=\ker \pi_1$ so $j_1(K_1),j_2(K_2)$ are normal. Their intersection is trivial because each has a constant coordinate at the identity. Their product is all of $G$ because $(a,b)=(1,b)(a,1)$.

$[2\implies 3]$ Now suppose the second condition. We shall first prove the kernel of the "multiplication" is trivial. Note $(a,b)\in \ker \phi$ iff $a=b^{-1}$, i.e iff $(a,b)=(b^{-1},b)$. Since subgroups are closed under inversion, $b^{-1}\in H$. If $(a,b)\in \ker \phi$ necessarily also $b^{-1}\in N$ and so $b^{-1}\in H\cap N=\bf 0$ meaning $b=1=b^{-1}$. This proves $\ker \phi$ is trivial. The multiplication is a group homomorphism because normal subgroups commute pointwise.

$[3\implies 1]$ By assumption.

---

First of all, is my proof correct? I am worried I may have missed something and I don't want to miss any subtleties.

Second of all, I am wondering whether a proof of $[2\implies 3]$ can avoid inverses and thus generalize to monoids and perhaps even unital categories in general. If not, what's a more categorical approach? The same argument I gave holds for vector space etc...

Comment: The difficulty with thinking about products of groups is that they satisfy two universal properties. One is the usual universal property of products. The other is that the product is also the "commutative coproduct": it's the universal group equipped with a map from the two given groups whose images commute (this is related to your second characterization). There are a few other contexts, e.g. Lie algebras and algebras, where such a universal property makes sense to state, but I haven't thought about what it might mean in general.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan this property of pointwise commutation of images is called "cooperation" in the context of unital categories. See chapter 1 of [this book](https://goo.gl/EYQeEW). My question is motivated by the fact the book proves no implication analogous to $3\implies 1$. Are there errors in my proof?

Comment: The implication $2 \Rightarrow 3$ could have more detail: (a) You never define $\phi:N\times H \to G$ (i.e. as the map $(a,b) \mapsto ab$); (b) Your explanation that $\phi$ is a homomorphism could be clearer (since normal subgroups don't always commute pointwise) i.e. this follows from the fact that they are normal and have trivial intersection (since then every commutator $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ where $a\in N$ and $b \in H$ will be in $N\cap H$.)